# FileNotFoundError pointing to the wrong drive letter using Python's df2gspread

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, oauth-2.0

The code I'm trying to run is pretty simple, trying to send a Pandas DataFrame to Google Sheets using the df2gspread package.

```
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
import pandas as pd

df = live_data()
spreadsheet = 'my_spreadsheet_key'
wks_name = 'my_sheet_name'
d2g.upload(df, spreadsheet, wks_name)
```

When I run that base script from PowerShell, I get the following error message.

```
C:\users\USER\github> python script_Folder\my_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 122, in _loadfile
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'O:\\/.gdrive_private'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_Folder\my_script.py", line 177, in <module>
    d2g.upload(df_liveTiming, spreadsheet, wks_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\df2gspread\df2gspread.py", line 76, in upload
    credentials = get_credentials(credentials)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\df2gspread\utils.py", line 77, in get_credentials
    client_secret_file, SCOPES)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 2105, in flow_from_clientsecrets
    cache=cache)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 166, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 126, in _loadfile
    exc.strerror, exc.errno)
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'O:\\/.gdrive_private', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

The O:\ drive is a network drive for my work, and I have no idea how it is inserting itself into this script all of a sudden. The .gdrive_private folder is located in my home directory, as instructed in the [df2gspread documentation](http://df2gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#access-credentials).

I've tried to investigate the system variables to make sure there wasn't something out of place but I didn't see anything. I've tried walking through the scripts it lists in the error message but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on here?

Comment: My guess is that O:\ is your "real" home directory, and that script just fails spectacularly there expecting a POSIX system; after all it also has `/` which is the POSIX directory separator.

Comment: Put a `import os` and `os.getcwd()` at the beginning of the code and post the output please.

Comment: I ran it with the os.getcwd() command and it said its current working directory was C:\users\USER\github\script_Folder\